# Why does ArrayBuffer change value?

Tags: javascript, buffer

Why does the buffer also change when I change `positionView` and `colorView`?

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(nbrOfVertices * vertexSizeInBytes);
var positionView = new Float32Array(buffer);
var colorView = new Uint8Array(buffer);
```

Comment: What do you mean by _changed_? Seems to stay the same for me…

Comment: Both of the views write to the same underlying buffer. Copy it if you need them to be separate.

Comment: Oh, you mean, when you actually assign values to `positionView` or `colorView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All [typed array structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) are *views* upon an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer). They allow you to access and modify the underlying binary data within the [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) in a choosen layout such as 32bit floats.**

If you want to create separate buffers you could just create your position- and colorbuffers by using the number of vertices multiplied by the number of components as argument, this implicitly creates an underlying [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) accessable via the `buffer` property of the view.

```
var numVertices = 4;
var positions = new Float32Array(numVertices * 3 /*position: x, y, z*/);
var colors = new Uint8Array(numVertices * 4 /*color: r, g, b, a*/);
```

If you're trying to set up an interlaced VertexBuffer with the layout: `f32pX,f32pY,f32pZ,ui8cR,ui8cG,ui8cB,ui8cA` "on the fly" 
your colorView also "views" the float data, so you have to offset your writings by 12 byte.

```
var positionOffset = 3 * 4;//3 positions with 4 byte each
var bufferOffset = positionOffset+4;//each color component is 1 byte
for (
  var colorStart = positionOffset;
  colorStart < colorView.length;
  colorStart += bufferOffset
) {
  colorView[colorStart]=r;
  colorView[colorStart+1]=g;
  colorView[colorStart+2]=b;
  colorView[colorStart+3]=a;
}
```